# I have a collection "customer" and in which I have a list which is of collection "Environment" I want to update list at particular Index

Tags: java, spring-boot

```java
public Class Customer{
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String companyName;
    private List<Environment> environment = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```java
public Class Environment{
    private int clusterid;
    private string clusterName
}
```

My Collection in Mongo

```json
{  
  "id":1,
  "name":"xyz",
  "companyName":"abc",
  "environment":[
    {
      "clusterid":2,
      "clusterName":"qwe"
    },
    {
      "clusterid":6,
      "clusterName":nme"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to update environment List of index 2 with returning whole environment List.  How do I do this with spring boot?  I want to update particular index of list fetching other too in the collection .

```java
public int updateEnv(Customer customer) {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("id").is(customer.getid()));
    Update update = new Update();
    update.set("environment", customer.getEnvironment());
    return mongoUtil.update(query, update, Customer.class);
}
```

I have tried this it is updating when environmentList contains 1 array and if it is having more than 1, it is removing others and sets the data sent by postman

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,check this link and edit the question so we can understand.

Comment: *"environment List of index 2"* --- That would cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, since indexes are zero-based, i.e. there is no index 2 in a list of size 2, only index 0 and 1.

Comment: "index 2" is for the purpose of example . just suppose I am having environment List in customer collection as I indicated example  if I am updating env list  with a "clusterid":6, the above query also remvoe the "clusterid":2 . I dont want to change that i just want to edit info regarding of particular index of environment List